# Using Julia PyCall, to use matplotlib.pyplot, inside a Julia module

Tags: module, julia, precompile, pyobject

I'm using

- MacOS 10.13.6, High Sierra
- From terminal, julia -- version yields julia version 1.0.1
- From terminal, python --version yields Python 2.7.15
- Running scripts from terminal

I have a small Julia script that works after a [fix](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/164) that I found from googling:

**File: standalone.jl (works)**

```
using PyCall

@pyimport matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg") # Required on Mac, otherwise I get an error: "-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f85e1050280...."
@pyimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2]
y = [1, 2]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I would like to know how to re-cast this script into a module file and a main file in the following way (adjusted from the [documentation](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#using-pycall-from-julia-modules)):

**File: getplt.jl**

```
__precompile__() # this module is safe to precompile
module getplt
using PyCall

const plt = PyNULL()
const mpl = PyNULL()

function __init__()
  copy!(plt, pyimport_conda("matplotlib.pyplot", "matplotlib"))
  copy!(mpl, pyimport_conda("matplotlib", "matplotlib"))
end

end
```

**File: main.jl**

```
push!(LOAD_PATH, "./")
using getplt

getplt.mpl[:use]("TkAgg") # Required on Mac

x = [1, 2]
y = [0, 2]

getplt.plt[:figure]
getplt.plt[:plot](x, y)
getplt.plt[:show]
```

When I tried doing this, I get the following error:

```
-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9e78221710
2018-10-30 16:11:44.897 julia[87599:2109977] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9e78221710'
*** First throw call stack:
(
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4697f2db __exceptionPreprocess + 171
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6db22c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff46a17db4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
  3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff468f5820 ___forwarding___ + 1456
  4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff468f51e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
  5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000134d5531d TkpInit + 413
  6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000134cad17e Initialize + 2622
  7   _tkinter.cpython-37m-darwin.so      0x0000000134295a0f _tkinter_create + 1183
  8   libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201dc29 _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 681
  9   libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201dd2d _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords + 45
  10  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x0000000122127714 call_function + 612
  11  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211e7fa _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 8138
  12  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211c399 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3305
  13  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201cb21 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 481
  14  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201e514 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 164
  15  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x0000000122085eda slot_tp_init + 298
  16  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012208f5d7 type_call + 295
  17  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201d7e3 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 691
  18  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012212777c call_function + 716
  19  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211e927 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 8439
  20  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201d3de function_code_fastcall + 254
  21  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x0000000122127786 call_function + 726
  22  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211e7fa _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 8138
  23  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211c399 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3305
  24  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201cb21 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 481
  25  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201e514 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 164
  26  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201ff24 method_call + 36
  27  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201df26 PyObject_Call + 246
  28  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211eb73 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 9027
  29  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211c399 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3305
  30  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201d966 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 230
  31  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x0000000122127786 call_function + 726
  32  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211e88e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 8286
  33  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201d3de function_code_fastcall + 254
  34  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x0000000122127786 call_function + 726
  35  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211e88e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 8286
  36  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211c399 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3305
  37  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201d966 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 230
  38  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x0000000122127786 call_function + 726
  39  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211e88e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 8286
  40  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012211c399 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3305
  41  libpython3.7m.dylib                 0x000000012201cb21 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 481
  42  ???                                 0x0000000121cad41a 0x0 + 4861907994
  43  ???                                 0x0000000121cb20c4 0x0 + 4861927620
  44  ???                                 0x0000000121cae6d4 0x0 + 4861912788
  45  ???                                 0x0000000121cae633 0x0 + 4861912627
  46  libjulia.1.0.dylib                  0x0000000104848ac3 jl_fptr_trampoline + 51
  47  libjulia.1.0.dylib                  0x00000001048594b2 jl_f__apply + 1218
  48  ???                                 0x0000000121cae4ee 0x0 + 4861912302
  49  libjulia.1.0.dylib                  0x0000000104848ac3 jl_fptr_trampoline + 51
  50  libjulia.1.0.dylib                  0x0000000104a0dab8 do_call + 200
  51  libjulia.1.0.dylib                  0x0000000104a0c5ac eval_body + 1228
  52  libjulia.1.0.dylib                  0x0000000104a0caf8 jl_interpret_toplevel_thunk_callback + 408
  53  libjulia.1.0.dylib                  0x000000010485f68c enter_interpreter_frame + 28
  54  libjulia.1.0.dylib                  0x00000001048796c2 jl_toplevel_eval_flex + 1282
  55  libjulia.1.0.dylib                  0x0000000104854ebf jl_parse_eval_all + 1279
  56  libjulia.1.0.dylib                  0x000000010487a9e3 jl_load_ + 115
  57  sys.dylib                           0x000000010d96c9fa japi1_include_relative_2907.clone_1.clone_2 + 1178
  58  sys.dylib                           0x000000010d45a18d japi1_include_3913.clone_1 + 189
  59  sys.dylib                           0x000000010d459ea0 japi1__start_2552.clone_1 + 704
  60  julia                               0x000000010483b48d true_main + 1341
  61  julia                               0x000000010483aecc main + 108
  62  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6e73c015 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

signal (6): Abort trap: 6
in expression starting at /Users/.../main.jl:10
__pthread_kill at /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib (unknown line)
Allocations: 6553408 (Pool: 6552271; Big: 1137); GC: 14
Abort trap: 6
```

Please, let me know if any further information is needed, and any help in overcoming this error is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

My tentative solution, which doesn't answer this question, is to simply use the Plots package (which *does* work inside modules) and not using PyPlot. I'm going to leave this question open for the time being, as I may like to use matplotlib.pyplot sometime in the future and I hope that this error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Codes and Documentation of PyPlot

https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl

I recommended you to use the PyPlot Library. Plotting for Julia based on matplotlib.pyplot.

Use the commands (Do this in terminal mode, IPython sometimes crushes)

using Pkg

Pkg.add("PyCall")
Pkg.add("PyPlot")

I think this solves your problem
Pkg.build("PyCall") 
Pkg.build("PyPlot")

using PyCall 
using PyPlot

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please see the comment I left on @Przemyslaw's answer. I believe the same applies to this answer, unfortunately.

Comment: You must use Plots.jl, It's solve your ploblem, and is a native lib of Julia. I will share you, a example using Plots. In this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CkzV4Wxqpll_gb8Nd43O7OawrEJg3vSZ). Enjoy it.

Comment: If you have some problem using MAC and Plots.jl, see this [link](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/571). Perhaps solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use `PyPlot.jl` to use matplotlib in Julia.

However, you **have to** import it before calling any matplotlib operation via PyCall. Follow the steps below:

(1) Install `PyPlot` module with the Julia package manager (press `]` and run add PyPlot)

(2) Add a new line at the beginning of your code:

```
using PyPlot
```

Now the calls to `matplolib` will not crash Julia. The line `matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` might not be required (I do not have a Mac to test).

Here is a MWE with a module:

```
module M1
using PyCall
using PyPlot
@pyimport matplotlib.pyplot as pyplt
function makeplot()    
    pyplt.plot(1:10,(1:10).^2)
end
end

using Main.M1
M1.makeplot()
```

Having that said consider using `Plots.jl` for plotting - this allows you have a single code in Julia that plots on several backends. When making choices regarding to plotting I always find this page very helpfull: http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/backends/.

Comment: I've tried simply `using PyPlot`. This works in the REPL, but not when used from a module (I've updated my link to be more specific). In case I'm wrong, could you provide a minimum working example?

Comment: I provided MWE - works on Windows (I do not have a Mac) but it should work too (the key is not to forget to import PyPlot)

Comment: Hm, this must be an issue related to Mac. When I try running this, I get the same looking error in my post.